# How to maintain aspect ratio of image thumbnail

Tags: php, image

How to maintain aspect ratio of image thumbnail so they don't look squashed?

```
  protected function DisplayPhoto($Sender) {
        $body = $Sender->EventArguments['Discussion']->Body;
        preg_match('#\<img(.+?)src=(.+?)\>#s', $body, $matches);
              if(isset($matches[2])){
                    $image = "src=" . $matches[2];
                    echo '<img class="ProfilePhotoSmall"' . $image . '>';
              }else{
                    //do what you want
              }       
  }
```

Here is the CSS.

```
ul.Discussions li img {
height: 60px;
width: 110px;
padding: 0 6px 0 4px;
float: right;
position: relative;
}

.Discussion.ItemContent {
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
display: inline;
}
```

Comment: What does the CSS look like for `.ProfilePhotoSmall`? Other than inside the CSS, I can't find any way you've changed the size of the image?

Comment: The css is provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of specifying both a `width` and `height` rule in CSS, simply specify one of them (which one will depend upon the way you want the scaling). The omission of one will have the browser maintain the aspect ratio:

```
ul.Discussions li img {
    width: 110px;
    padding: 0 6px 0 4px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
```

The above code will resize the image to a width of `110px`, and the height will be automatically calculated by the browser.

Comment: +1 Small addition: If you want a fixed-sized box for your image, you can set it as a background image and use `background-size: cover` to have the image scale in proportion to cover the whole box.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you changing image size, but the logic will be something like this:

Let's say you have an image of `300px width` and `150px height`.
Find the ratio, which is `2` here. And when you give a new width to the image, example `250px`.
Divide `250px/2` to find the corresponding height. New width is `250px` and height is `125px`.

It is just a basic logic to give you a hint

***Note that you can't resize of images by CSS, it will just resize it for the user. It will load a bigger image than it needs***